# How to remove comma between date and time on toLocaleString() in Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, locale

```js
var date ="03/05/2013";
var localDate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
var localTime = "20:41"
var UTCDateTime = localDate+ "T" + localTime +":00.000Z";
localDateTime = new Date(UTCDateTime)

var options = { hour12: false, day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' };
console.log("Date:>>"+localDateTime.toLocaleString('en', options));
```

How do you remove comma after date `Date:>>05/03/2013 21:41`

Answer (score 18):

I wouldn't replace the comma with either the `replace` function or a regex, because that could easily result in the wrong commas being removed. The short date format that you use in your example doesn't contain a comma in the date part, but a longer date format like `{ day: '2-digit', month: 'long', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' }` will.

A more resilient option is to format the date and time parts separately, and concatenate them with a space in between:

```
var date ="03/05/2013";
var localDate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
var localTime = "20:41"
var UTCDateTime = localDate+ "T" + localTime +":00.000Z";
localDateTime = new Date(UTCDateTime)

var dateOptions = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
var timeOptions = { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' };
console.log("Date:>>" + localDateTime.toLocaleDateString('en', dateOptions) + " " + localDateTime.toLocaleTimeString('en', timeOptions));
```

Comment: Sounds good, note that the second part must use toLocaleTimeString

Comment: The same is possible with two `Intl.DateTimeFormat` objects (which can be cached for performance reasons): `console.log("Date:>>" + new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', dateOptions).format(localDateTime) + " " + new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', timeOptions).format(localDateTime));`

Answer (score 8):

With `replace`:

```js
var date ="03/05/2013";
var localDate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
var localTime = "20:41"
var UTCDateTime = localDate+ "T" + localTime +":00.000Z";
localDateTime = new Date(UTCDateTime)

var options = { hour12: false, day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' };
console.log("Date:>>"+localDateTime.toLocaleString('en', options).replace(',',''));
```

Answer (score 3):

What's about using **regex**?

```
'01/01/2018, 12:00'.replace(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}), (\d{2}):(\d{2})/, '$1/$2/$3 $4:$5')
```

```js
var date            = '03/05/2013';
var localDate       = date.split('/').reverse().join('-');
var localTime       = '20:41';
var localDateTime   = new Date(localDate+ 'T' + localTime + ':00.000Z');

var options         = {hour12: false, day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'};
var output          = localDateTime.toLocaleString('en', options);
var outputFormatted = output.replace(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}), (\d{2}):(\d{2})/, '$1/$2/$3 $4:$5');

console.log(outputFormatted);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` function for your desired locale for this. Try the following code:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 02, 17, 12, 48, 00));
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {dateStyle: 'short', timeStyle: 'medium', hour12: false});
const arr = formatter.format(date).split(',');
const ans = `${arr[0]}${arr[1]}`;

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Please update the snippet demo above to show your solution.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea Intl even existed