# Why is JavaScript inserting commas in localized dates in some browsers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser, brave

Using "Date.toLocaleDateString" to get the date in a given language and format, some browsers have a comma after the year.

```js
const myDate = new Date().toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit'
})

console.log(myDate)
```

**Brave**  *Version  1.48.158 Chromium: 110.0.5481.77 (Official Build) 64 bits*

```
'09/02/2023, 10:52:42'
```

**Chrome** *Version 109.0.5414.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

```
'09/02/2023 10:52:32'
```

**Firefox** *109.0.1 (64-bits)*

```
'09/02/2023 10:52:32'
```

Why this difference if we are setting a specific locale ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982572/how-to-remove-comma-between-date-and-time-on-tolocalestring-in-js